# Intent.ACTION_SEND not working on Oreo

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo, share-intent

I am developing a custom camera application which captures a picture and stores it in the gallery. When I share that image using Intent.ACTION_SEND, it works absolutely fine on all devices except for devices having **API 26, i.e. OREO.**

My code to share the image is:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            Uri uriShare = Uri.fromFile(outFile);
            //outfile is the path of the image stored in the gallery
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriShare);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, ""));
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If `targetSdkVersion` is higher than **24**, then [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) is used to grant access.

Create an xml file(Path: `res\xml`) `provider_paths.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<root-path name="external_files" path="/" />
</paths>
```

Add a **Provider** in [AndroidManifest.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) under

```
 <provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

and **replace**

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(fileImagePath);
```

to

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",fileImagePath);
```

and you are done.

Comment: <provider> is contained in <application>.

Comment: What about videos? The same code is not working for sharing videos but is working for sharing images.

Comment: Perfect answer. 100% working

Comment: For modern day development replace:
android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
with
android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"

Answer (score 3):

Use **File Provider** for getting **IMAGE URI** and add flags to the intent... follow these steps carefully.. **[android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)** This update has been done since nougat..

Comment: shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);  will this help?

Comment: yes.. go through the link that i have posted..

Answer (score 0):

**For More Details**

Read this

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

**Source Code**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vfO43dMSt096CMp6nrOJNl3fJAf6MPwG

```
create xml folder inside providers_path.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.holostik.sharescreenshotexample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.holostik.sharescreenshotexample.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>


    </application>

</manifest>

package com.holostik.sharescreenshotexample;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.holostik.sharescreenshotexample.share.ScreenshotType;
import com.holostik.sharescreenshotexample.share.ScreenshotUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int n;
    String photoPath;

    LinearLayout rootContent;
    ImageView iv_share;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rootContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootContent);
        iv_share = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_share);

        iv_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

                    if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.e("MainActivity ", "P granted");

                        takeScreenshot(ScreenshotType.FULL);

                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                                }, 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Lower Than MarshMallow");
                    takeScreenshot(ScreenshotType.FULL);
                }

            }
        });

    }


    /*  Method which will take screenshot on Basis of Screenshot Type ENUM  */
    private void takeScreenshot(ScreenshotType screenshotType) {
        Bitmap b = null;
        switch (screenshotType) {
            case FULL:
                b = ScreenshotUtils.getScreenShot(rootContent);
                break;
            case CUSTOM:
                //If Screenshot type is CUSTOM
                break;
        }

        //If bitmap is not null
        if (b != null) {
//            showScreenShotImage(b);//show bitmap over imageview
            Log.e("keshav", "bitmap is -- > " + b);

            SaveImage(b);

            shareScreenshot();
      /*      File saveFile = ScreenshotUtils.getMainDirectoryName(MainActivity.this);//get the path to save screenshot
            File file = ScreenshotUtils.store(b, "screenshot" + screenshotType + ".jpg", saveFile);//save the screenshot to selected path
            shareScreenshot(file);//finally share screenshot
            Log.e("file Path", String.valueOf(file));
*/

        } else
            //If bitmap is null show toast message
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.screenshot_take_failed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap)
    {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /* TODO  Show screenshot Bitmap */
//    private void showScreenShotImage(Bitmap b) {
//        imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
//    }

    private void shareScreenshot()
    {
        photoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/saved_images" + "/Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        File F = new File(photoPath);
        //Uri U = Uri.fromFile(F);
        //  Uri U = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".my.package.name.provider", F);

        // TODO your package name as well add .fileprovider
        Uri U = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "com.holostik.sharescreenshotexample.fileprovider", F);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("image/png");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, U);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Email:"), 1);
    }

    // TODO Share Screen SHOT End ..............
}
```