# ACTION_GET_CONTENT does not allow moving or deleting files

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file

I'm trying to use Intent ACTION_GET_CONTENT to open an application such as (File Manager, File explorer etc...). However once I am in the File Manager, I am only able to open the file. The Copy to.. and Move to... capabilities are not shown when opening File Manager app using this method. Is ACTION_GET_CONTENT only used for opening files?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

Here is the image showing the open option only:

[image]

Comment: try this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781431/intent-action-send-not-working-on-oreo/48781560#48781560

Comment: Blame the programmers of those file manager apps. And yes ACTION_GET_CONTENT is only ment for getting content. Not for manupilating file system.

Comment: But if you have File Explorer apps installed you can open them manually. What is the problem?

Comment: `Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));` Wrong! That should be `Choose a file please`.

Comment: I know ACTION_VIEW allows almost full access to external applications but it shows too many app choices at once.