# Sending mail with attachment using intent in Nougat and above

Tags: java, android, uri

The code above is for sending an email with an attachment made before(fileToSend2). Works fine below Android Nougat (7.0) but is not working in Android Nougat 7.0 and Oreo 8.0. I update my device to Nougat and it is not working. Maybe for safety reason I must use provider to share the `Uri` file via intent. Can you help me how to do this?

```
        Uri u1 = Uri.fromFile(fileToSend2);

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "**Mail subject**");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail text");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"igirpenots55@yahoo.com"});
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u1);
        sendIntent.setType("text/html");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48781636/4168607

Comment: Gives me an error in Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",fileImagePath); in the MainActivity.this. What I have to use there?

Comment: `MainActivity.this` is context . Use your own Activity in place of it .