# Share image on other apps not working in Oreo 8.0

Tags: java, android

I am using this code to share the image on Whatsapp, Facebook, and Instagram etc.
This code works fine below API 25 but Not Working above API 25.

```
Intent share = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
                share.setType("image/jpeg");
                share.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", Uri.parse(this.imgUrl));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "via"));
```

Comment: Look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781431/intent-action-send-not-working-on-oreo

Comment: use fileprovider like this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781431/intent-action-send-not-working-on-oreo

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have added permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then use this code

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
Uri imageUri =  Uri.parse(this.imgUrl);                                
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
```

Comment: i have image uri "this.imgUrl" not an image in res/drawable.

Comment: I have an image uri  "this.imgUrl"  not an image in res/drawable.
I want to share image using this uri

Comment: your updated code does not work in Oreo 8.0. I have tested

Answer (score 1):

If targetSdkVersion is higher than 24, then [Provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) is used to grant access.

Create an xml file : res\xml\provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

now Add a Provider in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<provider
android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

and replace this with your code

```
Intent share = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
            share.setType("image/jpeg");
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+ ".provider",new File(this.imgUrl));
            share.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", uri);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "via"));
```

**Update**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path name="external_files" path="."/>
<cache-path name="external_files" path="."/>
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
<external-files-path name="external_files" path="."/>
<external-cache-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: getting image from another activity
String imgUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("ImgUrl");
then using this uri to 
share.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", Uri.parse(this.imgUrl));

Comment: Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+ ".provider","yout File path here");

here i have add this uri but error occured

Comment: ok I got your issue use new File(this.imgUrl), I have updated my answer too please vote up and accept if its right so other developer can use it if they got same issue. thanks

Comment: just delete .getPath()

Comment: Failed to find configured root that contains /file:/storage/emulated/0/Folder/IMG_20180812_065154.jpg

error on this line
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ImageDetail.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+ ".provider",
                        new File(this.imgUrl));

Comment: make sure you have file available in this path?

Comment: sure.i have this file

Comment: Replace path="."/> With path="Folder"/>

Comment: replacing "." with folder still not working.
when pressing share button activity restart

Comment: i think the problem is in provider_path.xml please read here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
     shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
     shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage); 
     shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use **File Provider** for getting **IMAGE URI** and add flags to the
>   intent...

follow these steps carefully.. [android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed) This update has been done since nougat..