# TransactionTooLargeException on API 28+ when sharing bitmap despite using Intent.EXTRA_STREAM

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bitmap

I am trying to share a bitmap via an intent to all apps that can handle images.Despite having follwed the instructions in several stack overflow answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806325/share-image-on-other-apps-not-working-in-oreo-8-0) and [on android developers](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#kotlin) my code produces as TransactionTooLargeException on API 28+ and some devices below. Eventhough i am always using Intent.EXTRA_STREAM and never send the bitmap direclty.

1. My first, simple approach:

```
         val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
                type = "image/jpeg"
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getImageUri(context!!, bitmap))
            }
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image"))



     fun getImageUri(inContext: Context, inImage: Bitmap): Uri {
    val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes)
    val path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.contentResolver, inImage, "Title", null)
    return Uri.parse(path) }
```

2. I also tried retrieving the uri via provider:

   ```
       <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
           android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
           tools:replace="android:resource" />
   </provider>
   ```

provider_paths.xml:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path name="external_files" path="."/>
<cache-path name="external_files" path="."/>
<cache-path name="shared_images" path="images/"/>
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
<external-files-path name="external_files" path="."/>
<external-cache-path name="external_files" path="."/>
```

Retrieve the uri, continue like in 1.:

```
  val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(it.activity, "...", file)
```

Stacktrace originating from my 1. approach:

```
    2019-06-02 17:10:51.255 19592-19592/... E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 9344028)
2019-06-02 17:10:51.292 19592-19592/... E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ..., PID: 19592
    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 9344028 bytes
        at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3998)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6635)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 9344028 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:774)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:4723)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3982)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6635) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

PS: I have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to my manifest

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace, and indicate which of your approaches that stack trace came from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out you just have to add this to your activity.
It clears the Activity's bundle of the subsidiary fragments' bundles.

```
 override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        //FIX: TransactionTooLargeException when sharing image via intent. Clear the Activity's bundle of the subsidiary fragments' bundles.
        outState.clear()
    }
```