# Move from Fragment to Activity Causes android.os.TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying to move from a Fragment to an Activity using Intents, and where I run my code, it causes `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException`.

My Fragment code (CardFragment.java):

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    txtName = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    btnFood = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_food);

    txtName.setText(mName);

    Bitmap bm = StringToBitMap(mImage);
    btnFood.setImageBitmap(bm);

    btnFood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Recipes.class);
            intent.putExtra("Name", mName);
            intent.putExtra("Recipe", mRecipe);
            intent.putExtra("Image", mImage);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

The `mName`, `mRecipe` and `mImage` are String variables.

My Activity code (Recipes.java):

```
public class Recipes extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipes);

        TextView txtName = findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        TextView txtRecipe = findViewById(R.id.txt_recipe);
        ImageView imgView = findViewById(R.id.img_view);

        txtName.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Name"));
        txtRecipe.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Recipe"));

        Bitmap bm = CardFragment.StringToBitMap(getIntent().getStringExtra("Image"));
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
}
```

Every time I run this code, I get this error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.company.recipeapp, PID: 12160
    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 2355168 bytes
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:161)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 2355168 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:540)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityTaskManager.java:4408)
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:145)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

What is this error and how can I solve it? Maybe because there are multiple `CardFragment`s in my previous view? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TransactionTooLargeException on API 28+ when sharing bitmap despite using Intent.EXTRA\_STREAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56416395/transactiontoolargeexception-on-api-28-when-sharing-bitmap-despite-using-intent)

Comment: Pass an identifier as the extra rather than your current values. Have the other activity use that identifier to get the needed data, such as retrieving it from a repository singleton. Or, perhaps you do not need a separate activity for that screen, and it can be another fragment within your original activity.

Comment: Looks like `mImage` is probably not a `String`, but a relatively large bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

This error means you sending more than 1 MB of data through intent, in this case, your bitmap is too large for intent.

The solution is to reduce bitmap size or use different ways to pass bitmap like services, etc.